# Git Clean removing the entire feature branch

Tags: bash, git

While entering the command `git clean -n` or `git clean -n -d` to check which files will be removed, it is also listing the entire feature branch along with the untracked files. 
If I run `git clean -f` will it remove the entire feature branch? What should I do, I only want to remove the untracked files.

Comment: It's important in general in Git to distinguish carefully between the *repository* (made up of commits and other objects, all distinguished by their hash IDs, plus *refs* or *references* like branch names that hold commit or other object hash IDs), the *index* (in which you build your next commit or resolve a merge), and the *work-tree*. The `git clean` command affects only the work-tree.

Answer (score 2):

`git clean` will not touch branches, but only remove untracked files. See [`git clean` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.